# Image field in edit mode still asking for image as a 'required' field

Tags: laravel-5.6, voyager

In the voyager backend, i set an image field as required in the BREAD section:

[image]

This works well in 'add' mode. image field will be validated if empty

Issue occurs in 'edit' mode. The image appears but on clicking on 'save', a prompt is thrown indicating the image field is empty(therefore requiring the image to be uploaded again):

[image]

therefore getting an 'Image field is required' prompt on edit. this appears to be a bug. Anyone experienced this issue and how did you fix it?

Comment: Seems like a missing feature; there are definitely cases where you'd want different validation for the create/edit states, like the `unique` rule. I'd consider opening an issue on the Voyager github page (or browsing open issues for a similar one)

Comment: Hi Tim. already opened a ticket. awaiting a response. though have resolved to solve the issue on my own by overriding the edit method. will see what i come up with

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution from the ticket i had raised on Voyager's github's page:

i.e. using `required_if` instead of `required`

`{ "validation": { "rule": "required_if:id,null", "messages": { "required": "your message" } } }`

here's the ticket:
[Voyager image edit issue](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3530)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution.

Comment: how can we use this for password field in voyager? i have used the same way but not work for me :(

Comment: What do you need @shazimali

Comment: i need to require password for store only not for update method.

Comment: "It's not really a solution. Because you can delete image and save without it." -- Someone said

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the rule on the column to the following

```
{
    "rule": "nullable"
}
```